# Concatenation of files.

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, concatenation

What is the best way to concatenate a series of multiple files in windows environment command prompt? 
 `Copy /b file1.mpg+file2.mpg newfile.mpg`

Works great, but I need a automated batch process to join handrends of them.

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any files in the directory that you don't want to include?

Comment: No. There aren't any files that have to be excluded.

Comment: Is the prefix `file` the same and are the files numbered continuously? Leading zeroes would circumvent the alpha sort ordering.

Comment: Exact names go like that... Movie_1...Movie_2...Movie_170...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to left-pad the numbers in the filenames with zeroes, you can count the number of files in the directory and then user a `for /L` loop to iterate over each one.

```
@echo off

:: Change this to wherever your files are located
set "source_dir=%userprofile%\Desktop\test_files"

:: Put the output file in the same directory as this script
set "target_file=%~dp0output.mpg"
echo(>%target_file%

:: Count the number of files in the source directory by searching the output
:: of dir /b for the number of lines that are not blank
for /F %%A in ('dir /b %source_dir% ^| find /c /v ""') do set "file_count=%%A"

:: Iterate over the entire set of files and merge them in order
for /L %%A in (1,1,%file_count%) do copy /b %target_file%+%source_dir%\file%%A.mpg %target_file%
```

Comment: @Vagelism22678 - how can I possibly be expected to know how to solve your problem if you aren't giving me any information? The fact that it's not a 0-byte file means that _something_ is working. What do you see if you get rid of the `@echo off` line and run it again?

Comment: My fault pal, I had to change the `file` to my files prefix. And also started the iteration from 0. Worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard.
`copy /b *.mpg newfile.mpg`

Comment: Thank you. Will this put the files in the correct sequence? 1...2...3...etc?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Unfortunately it goes in alphabetical order.